# Retrieving Shipping Address and user information from Billing Agreement via PayPal REST API

Tags: python, rest, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I have been able to successfully set up one time payments (which return Shipping and Payer information) and the majority of the Billing Plan/Billing Agreement functionality on my website using the paypalrestsdk (python in a django application).

After creating the Billing Plan, activating, then redirecting the user to the returned Redirect URL, I am given a token.  I can then use that token to execute the Billing Agreement, which returns an id and a URL.  When using that ID to retrieve information (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#retrieve-an-agreement) about the Billing Agreement, I'm given some information about the Billing Agreement, but no information about the Payer [name, shipping address, email, etc].

Is this a known limitation of the REST API, or is there a known method to return shipping address and user information from a BillingAgreement after it's been created and Activated?

Comment: Hi Ron, have you find the answer? I'm facing the exact same problem.

Comment: No real answer.  Direct queries to Paypal's support suggested it was a bug/current limitation.  There was "no timeframe for where these items will be added to the Billing Plans method"

Comment: Ye, I eventually found https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/issues/155. This bug has had an anniversary.